# Update alterando um valor pelo outro na tabela

Tags: sql, sql-update

Qual `update` usaria para alterar um valor pelo outro em uma tabela.

Um `update` na tabela `produtos` coluna `cod_produto`.

Gostaria de uma *query* onde na tabela chamada `produtos` todos que contiverem na coluna `cod_produto` o valor `000001` sejam alterados na mesma coluna `cod_produto` para `000002`.

Comment: Acredito que fazendo um select na tabela produtos e dentro do for que percorre ele pode se inserir a query de update , pois assim vc tera um id da linha para realizar.... Veja se ajuda....

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 4):

Esta é a utilização mais básica do UPDATE:

```
UPDATE produtos SET cod_produto = "000002" WHERE cod_produto = "000001"
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Update/SimpleChange.sql).